# Store difference between two dates recursively and calculate time spent on web site

Tags: c#, sql, date, datetime

I have to find time spent on site so I choose to maintain 2 datetimes and a time in database so that I can save the difference between login time and logout time and store it in a table as a column `timespent`.

The time will be stored as `{00:16:58.413785200}` So I have add some amount of time recursively after each logout so that if he spent 10 minutes in his first login and 5 minutes in his 2nd login we have to store 15 min for timspent on site.

But the problem is I am not able to guess what happens if I want to add 2 minutes after 23:59:59.000000000. I know that the max time value is 23:59:59 that can be stored for time datatype in sql.

So how to achieve this? I have tried like this

```
 var _user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
 _user.EndTime = DateTime.Now;
 var _startTime = _user.StartTime;
 if (_user.TimeSpent != null)
 {
   _user.TimeSpent = _user.TimeSpent + (_user.EndTime - _startTime);
 }
 else
 {
   _user.TimeSpent = (_user.EndTime - _startTime);
 }
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I've usually saved the ticks (long for .net and bigint for sqlserver) and then used that value. Then the timespan would not be limited to only 23:59:59.

Comment: can you please suggest some code as per my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to switch the datatype on `TimeSpent` column to `bigint`. You should have a default value of 0 for the `TimeSpent` column aswell or handle it in your code.

```
var _user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);

_user.EndTime = DateTime.Now;
var _startTime = _user.StartTime;

TimeSpan timeSpent = _user.TimeSpent != null ? TimeSpan.FromTicks(_user.TimeSpent) : 0;
if (timeSpent > TimeSpan.Zero)
{
   timeSpent = timeSpent + (_user.EndTime - _startTime)
}
else
{
  timeSpent = _user.EndTime - _startTime
}

_user.TimeSpent = timeSpent.Ticks;

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple check to see if the end time < the start time. If it is, then assume start time was on the previous day. Something like this should work:

```
// _user.StartTime
TimeSpan startTime = TimeSpan.Parse("23:59:54");        

// DateTime.Now
DateTime now = new DateTime(2014, 04, 11, 00, 05, 00);

// Get the time portion of DateTime.Now
TimeSpan endTime = now - now.Date;


TimeSpan timeSpent = TimeSpan.Zero;

if (endTime > startTime)
    timeSpent = endTime - startTime;
else
    timeSpent = endTime - startTime + TimeSpan.FromHours(24);

Console.WriteLine(timeSpent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to store a DateTime value instead of just a Time value. This way you would not have such restrictions. Even if you found a workaround for the 24 hour problem, what would you do if a case comes where a user spent more than one day (as per time difference) ? So the better ways forward --

1. DateTime
2. Long value - in ticks, number of seconds, etc

But certainly not just the time. You will need to change your table schema for this and quite some code :-)

Comment: DateTimes should be stored in UTC if used in a context where multiple timezones apply. You would then apply the correct timezone for each user when presented.